# Docker-compose up fails because of "fugit" gem and this isn't even in my Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, rubygems

I am trying to run a docker container and it fails on this error:

```
app_1       | rake aborted!
app_1       | LoadError: cannot load such file -- fugit
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:41:in `rescue in require'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:27:in `require'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.6.0/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
app_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
...
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-scheduler-3.0.1/lib/sidekiq-scheduler.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
sidekiq_1   | /myapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1   | /myapp/rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
sidekiq_1   | /myapp/rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1   |
sidekiq_1   | Caused by:
sidekiq_1   | Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan:
sidekiq_1   |
sidekiq_1   | (See full trace by running task with --trace)
sidekiq_1   | rake aborted!
```

I don't have this file in my Gemfile, although I believe it may be caused by `sidekiq-scheduler` or `bootsnap` gem.

Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0'#, require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rb-readline'
end

# group :production do
#   gem 'mysql2'
# end

gem 'pg'

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  #letter opener
  gem 'letter_opener'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'bullet'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap'

# JQuery
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

#toastr
gem 'toastr_rails'

# Used for server-side processing of datatables.
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'ajax-datatables-rails'

# Ability to debug code in real time.
gem 'pry'

# Used for mass imports.
gem 'activerecord-import', git: "https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import"

# Sidekiq used for backgrounding tasks.
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-scheduler'

# CSV parsing.
gem 'csv'

# Text editor.
gem 'ckeditor_rails'

#user authentication
gem 'devise'

#for document validation
gem 'activestorage-validator'

# Generates a visual diagram to represent model relationships.
gem 'railroady'

#for date range picker
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails'

#datepicker
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'

#date-time-picker
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails'

#tag input
gem 'bootstrap-tagsinput-rails'

#bootstrap slider
gem 'bootstrap-slider-rails'

#pagination
gem 'will_paginate'

#nested associations
gem "cocoon"

# Convert number to words.
gem 'humanize'

# HTML to PDF conversion
gem 'wicked_pdf'
#gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

# Slack-ruby-client
gem 'slack-ruby-client'
gem 'eventmachine'
gem 'faye-websocket'
gem 'rails_best_practices'

# Message implementation
gem 'twilio-ruby'

# For sidekiq web
gem 'rack', '2.0.7'

# For detecting mime types
gem 'mime'

# to call the api from rails application
gem 'rest-client'

gem 'activerecord-session_store'

# To get the next available day after a provided day
gem 'chronic'

# To get current season for password attacks
gem 'ruby-seasons'

#active storage validation
gem 'active_storage_validations'

# necessary for AWS client
gem 'aws-sdk-rails'
gem 'aws-sdk-ec2'

gem 'terminal-table'
gem 'time_difference'

# For PDF generation
gem 'grover'
```

What am I missing that would cause this error to occur while trying to stand up the docker container? I don't understand why it doesn't fail anywhere except for in the docker container.

From what I can tell, this is happening when running `rake db:migrate` because of it showing "rake aborted"

I've also tried removing the `bootsnap` gem since a lot of the errors had references to it, but no luck. Still getting the same error.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1-alpine
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.0.2

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        binutils-gold \
        build-base \
        curl \
        file \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        git \
        less \
        libstdc++ \
        libffi-dev \
        libc-dev \ 
        linux-headers \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        libgcrypt-dev \
        make \
        netcat-openbsd \
        nodejs \
        openssl \
        pkgconfig \
        postgresql-dev \
        python \
        tzdata \
        yarn 

RUN gem install bundler -v 2.0.2
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
RUN bundle check || bundle install

COPY . /myapp
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "80"]
```

Comment: How is sidekiq-scheduler installed? It is not in your Gemfile as well.

Comment: It's in the gemfile. Both `gem 'sideikq'` and `gem 'sidekiq-scheduler'` are in the gemfile above.

Comment: I see. I was off SO for aw hile, when did they started adding scrollbars to code sources? 00

Comment: First thing I'd try is to try `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. I am unsure how your docker container has been configured/build. `fugit` gem is a runtime dependency of `rufus-scheduler` gem, which is dependency of `sidekiq-scheduler`. I find it extremely weird though that your environment managed to resolve both `schedulers` and then it fails on fugit...

Comment: But honestly I'd not expect `bundle exec` to help - it is isolated docker after all and we're failing on `Kernel#require`. Just bash to the container and check if `fugit` is installed within `/usr/local/bundle/gems/`

Comment: Will give it a shot in just a few moments. Seems that I may have to try rebuilding and running everything step by step to pinpoint what's going on here.

Comment: How are you installing gems in the container?

Comment: Updated post to include my dockerfile

Comment: I'm quite interested in you Gemfile.lock as well. :)

Comment: So I included my Gemfile.lock file, but I re-ran this entire thing again and had no problem. I'm not sure if something ran out of order, or what.